# Redirected to homepage when adding/editing custom fields

Tags: ee2, custom-fields, ee2-upgrades

After updating the system to 2.7.2 I am no longer able to add or edit channel fields. I just get redirected to my default homepage and the form doesn't submit.

Answer (score 1):

These types of issues are typically hard to pin-point, but I'd try two things first:

1. Re-download 2.7.2 and then replace your new 2.7.2 files/folders in case there was a corrupted or missing file in there somewhere. If that doesn't work...
2. After you've backed up everything up, start disabling fieldtypes one-by-one (and even extensions) to see if there's a third party culprit.

Comment: No fields work... had to roll it back to version 2.5.2. all works fine. Funny, just did a clean install with the same 2.7.2 files on another job and all is fine. Now worried about running the update for other jobs. Clean install just isn't practical for larger projects.

Comment: Could a file name in the root conflict with custom fields being added. Just can't get to the bottom of this - why custom field adding would redirect to default homepage. First stage parsing looks for a template. Could it also be a permissions issue??? I've tested all the files on a separate server and it works fine. I just don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the control panel theme directory was uploaded during the upgrade. Sounds like it may not have been or the js corrupted.

Comment: Theme is there...

Comment: Everything you've described indicates issues with the JS in the CP theme... Best to delete the CP theme directory and reupload from the new EE version. See any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Tried a clean install with a fresh download and still getting the same issue.

Comment: Same exact files worked fine on a separate test server.

Comment: That suggests it may be something about this server. Have you contacted the host to their 2 cents?

Comment: Right, found another post where a few people are having the same issue. The work around is to login via /admin.php instead of /system. This works!!! hallelujah!!, however it doesn't explain what is happening. My thought is that it's about permissions - files uploaded to the server take on a default set of permissions. Here's a clue - maybe. I noticed, delving in to the js/cp/custom_field.js permissions are 644 however on the server that works default permissions for the js file is 664. I strongly suspect that this might be the root cause.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and link to the post that helped you. Glad you ate sorted!